# Replace function in javascript is not replacing correct index of regex match

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a String and I am detecting some 'urls' and 'closing anchor tags' using regex expression. firstly I am using match function which is returning the list of 'urls' and 'closing anchor tags'. further if my first url is matching with the second url then I dont need to do anything and if it is not matching then I need to replace the closing anchor tag with the same urls. here is the string:-

"This message was sent to ${EmailAddress} because you asked us to keep you up to date with the latest news and offers from the company. If you do not wish to receive these emails, please unsubscribe ${optout()}. You can also change your email preferences on our website logging in at 'a tag' class="footer-link" href="https://sample-website">https://sample-website 'closing a tag'. Please do not reply to this email, as we are unable to respond from this email address. If you need support, please visit the Sample Help Center 'closing a tag'.

```
var regex3 = new RegExp(/<\/a.?>/gm); 
var regex4 = new RegExp(/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm);


var closingATag = footerContentPlainText.match(regex3);
var URLList = footerContentPlainText.match(regex4);


if(URLList != null){

 for(var j =0,k=0; j<URLList.length; j++,k++){

  if(j+1 != URLList.length) {


   if(URLList[j] != URLList[j+1]){

    footerContentPlainText = 
     footerContentPlainText.replace(closingATag[j],"<" + URLList[j] + ">");

   }

else if(URLList[j] == URLList[j+1]){

j++;
}
}
else{

if(URLaTags != null){

 footerContentPlainText = footerContentPlainText.replace(closingATag[k],"<" + URLList[j] + ">");
 }
 }
}
}
```

Although I am handing different scenarios for different type of strings but this is the scenario where I am stuck.

I expect the output, where last 'closing a tag' should be replaced by 3rd url i.e "https://support.samplewebsite.com/samplename".

Here I am not able to write a tag in actual format so I have used just text in place of the same

please help

Comment: This is very confusingly written. What are you actually trying to achieve? Because I suspect regex might not even be needed here.

Comment: I am detecting all urls and closing a tags using regex, present in the string is there any other way to detect them without using regex??

Comment: and here match function is returning array of 3 urls in var URLList  and 2 closing a tags  in closingATag array

Comment: You could parse the content as HTML then get every `a` tag out of it and see what the `href` point to. You can also get the content inside the `a` tags, assuming it's only going to be URLs. That might be enough. I don't know - as I said, it's confusing.

Comment: I need to show this content in a text area. parse the content as html in not a requirement.

Comment: for your convenience I say in this scenario last Else part is executing. what things you are not able to understand or seems confusing???

Comment: Could you show an example of the output in both cases as well?

Comment: Why are you replacing the closing `</a>` with a URL is completely unclear to me. Also, why is there repeated code. But probably more importantly - why are you deliberately inducing a null pointer exception. You would only get into the `else` part if `URLList` is `null`, yet you still try to take `URLList[j]` which, again, can only ever be `null` at this point and thus lead to an error.

Comment: replacing [</a>]  with url is my requirement, and sorry for the braces, I have corrected the position of the braces